# Flask-Admin: Create child objects along with parent in the "create" form

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

In my Flask/SQLAlchemy application I have SQLAlchemy classes Parent and Child, where all the interesting data about each Parent is in its children:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship(Child)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    name = Column(String)
```

I want to create Parents in the Flask-Admin UI, and when I create them I want to be able to create their Child objects at the same time. When I go to the "create" form in the default ModelView for Parent, I can only choose existing Child objects from a menu, not create new ones.

For example, when creating each parent I would like to have text fields where I can type the "names" of Child objects, so that when Flask-Admin creates the Parent, it also creates Child objects with those values in their "name" columns.

Is this possible with Flask-Admin? Or if not, how would I customize the Flask-Admin ModelView to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [inline models](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/#flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView.inline_models).

You can use them in your example with:

```
class ParentModelView(ModelView):
    inline_models = (Child, )
```